# ANTLR4 file for identifying calculator expressions

Tags: parsing, antlr4, lexer, parse-tree

I had copied a sample lexer and parser rules script from the ANTLR4 samples and was trying out locally. The file corresponds to the rules for a calculator to identify mathematical expressions. But it is throwing up the follwing error which I am unable to resolve unless I remove the left recursive rules for 'expr' completly. Rules are

```
    grammar Expr;

/** The start rule; begin parsing here. */
prog:   stat+ ; 

stat:   expr NEWLINE                
    |   ID '=' expr NEWLINE        
    |   NEWLINE                   
    ;

expr:   expr ('*'|'/') expr   
    |   expr ('+'|'-') expr   
    |   INT                    
    |   ID                    
    |   '(' expr ')'         
    ;

ID  :   [a-zA-Z]+ ;      // match identifiers 
INT :   [0-9]+ ;         // match integers
NEWLINE:'\r'? '\n' ;     // return newlines to parser (is end-statement signal)
WS  :   [ \t]+ -> skip ; // toss out whitespace
```

The error occured is given below :

```
    $ antlr4 Expr.g4
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IndexOutOfBoundsException: Index: 0, Size: 0
    at java.util.ArrayList.rangeCheck(ArrayList.java:657)
    at java.util.ArrayList.get(ArrayList.java:433)
    at org.antlr.v4.misc.OrderedHashMap.getElement(OrderedHashMap.java:46)
    at org.antlr.v4.analysis.LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.setAltASTPointers(LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.java:241)
    at org.antlr.v4.analysis.LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.translateLeftRecursiveRule(LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.java:162)
    at org.antlr.v4.analysis.LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.translateLeftRecursiveRules(LeftRecursiveRuleTransformer.java:89)
    at org.antlr.v4.semantics.SemanticPipeline.process(SemanticPipeline.java:94)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processNonCombinedGrammar(Tool.java:399)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.process(Tool.java:384)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.processGrammarsOnCommandLine(Tool.java:343)
    at org.antlr.v4.Tool.main(Tool.java:190)
```

Comment: This compiles fine for me with ANTLR 4.8. Which version of ANTLR are you using?

Comment: Hey @sepp2k teh issue was resolved now. Apparently i was using java 8 and antlr4 doesnt work well with 8 .installing java 7 fixed it. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The issue got fixed . Was raised due to incompatibility of antlr4 as of now with Java 8. Using java 7 fixed it. Thanks

Comment: what version are you using? antlr4 is working for me in java 8. Did it become broken in a later version?